# How to generate chaotic sequences from Chen's hyperchaotic system?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, chaos

I need to generate two chaotic sequences based on chen's hyperchaotic system.It has to be generated from the following four formulas

```
X=ay-x;
Y=-xz+dx+cy-q;
Y=xy-bz;
Q=x+k;
```

where a,b,c,d,x,y,z,q are all initialised as follows.
I need only X and Y
where

```
  X=[x1,x2,...x4n]
  Y=[y1,y2,...y4n]
  a=36 ;
  b=3 ;
  c=28 ;
  d=16 ;
  k=0.2 ;
  x=0.3 ;
  y=-0.4 ;
  z=1.2 ;
  q=1 ;
  n=256 ;
```

I tried the following code but i'm not able to get it properly.

```
clc

clear all

close all

w=imread('C:\Users\Desktop\a.png');

[m n]=size(w)

a=36;

b=3;

c=28;

d=16;

k=0.2;

x(1)=0.3;

y(1)=-0.4;

z(1)=1.2;

q(1)=1;

for i=1:1:4(n)

  x(i+1)=(a*(y(i)-x(i)));

  y(i+1)=-(x(i)*z(i))+(d*x(i))+(c*y(i))-q(i);

  z(i+1)=(x(i)*y(i))-(b*z(i));

  q(i+1)=x(i)+k;

end

disp(x);

disp(y);
```

pls help. thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are trying to integrate a system of ordinary differential equations. It is not normally a good idea to implement the numerical integration yourself. Instead, have a look at Matlab's [built-in functionality](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code isn't even close to doing what you want it to. Fortunately, I'm vaguely interested in the problem and I have a bunch of spare time, so I thought I'd try and implement it step by step to show you what to do. I've left a few gaps for you to fill in.

It sounds like you want to integrate the hyperchaotic chen system, which has various definitions online, but you seem to be focusing on

[image]

So let's write a matlab function that defines that system

```
function vdot = chen(t, v, a, b, c, d, k)

    % Here you unpack the input vector v -
    x = v(1); y = v(2); z = v(3); q = v(4);

    % Here you need to implement your equations as xdot, ydot etc.
    %   xdot = ...
    %   ydot = ...
    % I'll leave that for you to do yourself.

    % Then you pack them up into an output vector -
    vdot = [xdot; ydot; zdot; qdot];

end
```

Save that in a file called `chen.m`. Now you need to define the values of the parameters a, b, c, d and k, as well as your initial condition.

```
% You need to define the values of a, b, c, d, k here.
%    a = ...
%    b = ...
% You also need to define the vector v0, which is a 4x1 vector of your
% initial conditions
%    v0 = ...
%
```

This next line creates a function that can be used by Matlab's integration routines. The first parameter `t` is the current time (which you don't actually use) and the second parameter is a `4x1` vector containing x, y, z, q.

```
>> fun = @(t,v) chen(t,v,a,b,c,d,k)
```

Now you can use `ode45` (which does numerical integration using a 4th order runge-kutta scheme) to integrate it and plot some paths. The first argument to `ode45` is the function you want to be integrated, the second argument is the timespan to be integrated over (I chose to integrate from 0 to 100, maybe you want to do something different) and the third argument is your initial condition (which hopefully you already defined).

```
>> [t, v] = ode45(fun, [0 100], v0);
```

The outputs are `t`, a vector of times, and `v`, which will be a matrix whose columns are the different components (x, y, z, q) and whose rows are the values of the components at each point in time. So you can pull out a column for each of the x and y components, and plot them

```
>> x = v(:,1);
>> y = v(:,2);
>> plot(x,y)
```

Which gives a reasonably chaotic looking plot:

[image]

Comment: i have a doubt sir...why do we use 't' here when we're not even using the values...

Comment: Because the `ode45` routine requires a function whose first argument is the current time, and whose second argument is the state of the system at time t.

Comment: if i use any other method to solve these equations then how would i get the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

@Abirami Anbalagan and Sir @Chris Taylor, I have also studied hyperchaotic system up to some extent. According to me, for system to be chaotic, values should be like
a= 35; b= 3; c= 12; d= 7;
v(n) = [-422 -274 0 -2.4]transpose
where v(n) is a 4*1 Matrix.